# Asynchronously update a custom element with an iron-ajax response

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, lit-element, iron-ajax

I am relatively new to lit-element, I took a crack at creating an element that has a checkbox which ideally should get checked based on the response to an ajax call. What I run my code, the checkbox is always checked regardless of the ajax response. I also get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (fhir-active-status.js:57)
    at HTMLElement.fire (legacy-element-mixin.js:630)
    at HTMLElement._handleResponse (iron-ajax.js:551)
```

I think its a life-cycle problem but I can't figure it out. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';
import '@material/mwc-formfield/mwc-formfield.js';
import '@material/mwc-checkbox/mwc-checkbox.js'
import '@polymer/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.js';

class FhirActiveStatus extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            /**activeStatus is used to show active status of person true or false. Use this property to show/hide. Default: true */
            activeStatus: {type:String},
            /**url is used to make AJAX call to FHIR resource. Default: null */
            url: {type:String},
            /**value is used to take the input value of each field*/
            value: {type:Boolean},
        }
    }

    /**default value of properties set in constructor*/
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.activeStatus = 'true';
        this.value = false;
        this.url = "";
    }


   async updated() {
            this.shadowRoot.getElementById('ajax').addEventListener('iron-ajax-response', function (e) {
            var active = this.parentNode.host;
            if (e.detail.response.active) {
                active.shadowRoot.querySelector('.activeState').checked = true;

            }
            else if (!e.detail.response.active) {
                active.shadowRoot.querySelector('.activeState').checked = false;
            }
            else {
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.querySelector('#activeDiv'));
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return html`
       <div id="activeDiv">
       ${this.activeStatus !== 'false' ? html`<mwc-formfield class="activeStatus" alignEnd label="ACTIVE STATUS:">
         <mwc-checkbox id="active" checked="${this.value}" class="activeState" on-click="${e => this.value = e.target.value}"></mwc-checkbox>
         </mwc-formfield>` : ''}
         <iron-ajax id="ajax" bubbles auto handle-as="json" url="${this.url}"></iron-ajax>
       </div>
    `;
    }
}

window.customElements.define('fhir-active-status', FhirActiveStatus);
```

Comment: at first (very quick) sight it looks like you need to switch ``parentNode`` for ``getRootNode()`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode

Answer (score 1):

`updated` can fire when the component isn't connected, so  `this.parentNode` or  `this.parentNode.host` will be empty. The `on-` prefix isn't supported by Lit. You're using `this.parentNode.removeChild` to remove an element on update, but that element is managed by the template. You're using `querySelector('.activeState')` but even if this was on the right `shadowRoot` it would be error prone because that element will only be in the template when `this.activeStatus !== 'false'`.

Instead use the built in `@event` handlers in Lit, and rely on the component lifecycle to do work for you rather than trying to override it.

```
async ajaxResponse(e) {
    // Set properties in events, these will automatically queue up a render
    // You don't need to manipulate the DOM here
    this.value = e.detail.response.active;
    this.activeStatus = 'false';
}

render() {
    // This will be called after properties have changed
    // So if @iron-ajax-response calls this.ajaxResponse, 
    // and this.ajaxResponse sets this.activeStatus = 'false'
    // then this will be called again and hide the <mwc-* fields
    return html`
<div id="activeDiv">
    ${this.activeStatus !== 'false' ? html`
    <mwc-formfield class="activeStatus" alignEnd label="ACTIVE STATUS:">
        <mwc-checkbox id="active" checked=${this.value} class="activeState" 
             @click=${e => this.value = e.target.value}></mwc-checkbox>
    </mwc-formfield>` : ''}
         
    <iron-ajax id="ajax" bubbles auto handle-as="json" url=${this.url}
        @iron-ajax-response=${this.ajaxResponse}></iron-ajax>
</div>`;
}
```